# Searching for lines matching a criterion: where am i going wrong?

Tags: search

I am trying to record all the lines with the word `bad` in a Emacs-buffer
with a simple elisp function

```
(defun bad-line-numbers ()
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (setq sec-lines ())
  (while (re-search-forward "bad" t nil nil) 
    (cons (thing-at-point 'line) sec-lines ))
  (message sec-lines)
  )
```

I tried this function, by evaluating `(bad-line-numbers)` in a buffer but I get the error `Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, t` after the point goes to the beginning of the buffer.
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the things pointed out by @muffinmad, the code doesn't record the information found by the search.

The body of the loop is `(cons .... sec-lines)`, which creates a new list containing the search result and whatever is in the list `sec-lines`. However, this new list is thrown away.

You can either write `(setq set-lines (cons ... sec-lines))` or, simpler, `(push ... sec-lines)`.

Some other things:

- The arguments to `re-search-forward` are wrong, typically you pass `nil` as *bound* and `t` as *noerror*.
- You'll need to change the last line to `(message "%s" sec-lines)`.
- To avoid moving the point, you can wrap everything in a `save-excursion`.

All included, the following would work:

```
(defun bad-line-numbers ()
  "Return list of lines containing `bad'."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((sec-lines ()))
      (while (re-search-forward "bad" nil t)
        (push (thing-at-point 'line) sec-lines))
      (message "%s" sec-lines)
      (nreverse sec-lines))))
```

Note that `(things-at-line 'line)` returns the full line. To find the line number (which the title indicates) you can use `(line-number-at-pos)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. From `C-h f beginning-of-buffer`:

   ```
   This function is for interactive use only;
   in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-min))' instead.
   ```
2. From `C-h f re-search-forward`:

   ```
   The optional second argument BOUND is a buffer position that bounds
   the search.
   ```

   You passed `t` as second argument while it must be integer or marker. If you want to leave the second argument unspecified you can pass `nil` for it.